# bge mouse move camera

Tags: game-engine

I want the mouse to move the camera.  Now I don't want to rotate the camera.  I am trying to make a top-down space themed game.  I would like something where I can move the mouse close to the edge of the window, and it moves the camera in that direction.  I'm guessing I would have to use python, which I'm pretty good at, but I can't find out how to make python move the camera. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you do not need Python (you can use it but you do not need it).

## Concept

Add an overlay scene to your game (if you do not have one already).
Add a plane at each single side of the camera's view. The plane can be invisible.

Now you can add a mouse over sensor to each single plane. When the mouse is over the plane send a message. For example, the left plane sends "scroll left".

Now you can add logic that let the camera move according to the messages it receives. For example, when "scroll left" you move the camera along -Y.

I hope it helps